# Making the while loop synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've got a following piece of code

```
var page = 2;
var last_page = 100;
while(page <= last_page) {
  request("http://some_json_server.com/data?page=" + page, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      store_data(body)
    }
    page++;
  });                
}
```

I've done the following, but it is actually not retrieving anything. Am I doing this correctly?

```
var page = 2;
var last_page = 100;
while(page <= last_page) {
var async_arr = [];
async_arr.push(
  function(next) {
    request("http://some_api_url?page=" + page, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        store_data(body);
      }
    });
  }
);

async.series(
  async_arr, done
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async#series

Comment: Regarding your edit, you have to call next() in the request callback

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for [async.whilst()](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst). This solution is assuming you actually want to do each request after the other. As @UpTheCreek mentions (*edit*: the comment I referred to was edited) it would likely be possible to do it asynchronously and keep track of each result using `async.parallel`.

```
var page = 2,
    lastPage = 100;

async.whilst(function () {
  return page <= lastPage;
},
function (next) {
  request("http://some_json_server.com/data?page=" + page, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      store_data(body)
    }
    page++;
    next();
  });
},
function (err) {
  // All things are done!
});
```

Comment: Damn, I wish you had answered my question I just asked just now. I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 55):

With `while` you get a busy loop, which is counter-purpose in Node.

Make it a recursive function instead. Each call will be done in a separate tick.

```
var page = 2;
var last_page = 100;

(function loop() {
    if (page <= last_page) {
        request("/data?page=" + page, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                store_data(body)
            }
            page++;
            loop();
        });
    }
}());
```

Comment: +1 What if you didn't know the number of pages? How would you handle this @katspaugh

Comment: @TheGrayFox, the response should somehow indicate either the number of pages, or just send you no data so you know you shouldn't make the next request.

Comment: A recursive function will eventually eat up all of your memory and you will exceed your call stack size.

Comment: @EricUldall if it's infinite and synchronous recursion, it will. But the recursion in _this_ case is async (callback-based) and limited to 100 iterations. Mythbusted?

Comment: @katspaugh assuming the use case never exceeds page 100 it will probably not cause any problems and its recursion only occurs inside of the request callback it will probably not cause issue. Just something good to note if you plan on using this pattern.

Comment: @EricUldall I am running into the same problem. Call stack exceeded. However I want to, precisely obtain what this pattern proposes. Make REST calls continuously in an infinite loop. What do you advice then as the best way, clean and that allows the garbage collection to happen without using recursion please?

Comment: I think you should look into using the http agent. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options I've found that you can get far better control over large number of http requests by using the agent as a custom request pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your while loop in async and break after your promise resolves/conditions have been met...

```
    const request = require("request")

    ;(async()=>{

    let results = []
    while(true){
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        request('http://www.seanbehan.com/', (err, resp, body)=>{
          console.log(new Date, 'Downloading..')
          results.push(body)
          resolve(body)
        })
      })

      if(results.length >= 5){
        break
      }
    }

    console.log(results)
  })()
```