# Open URI - Opening multiple pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-uri

Using Node's [open-uri](https://github.com/publicclass/open-uri) module, is it possible to open multiple pages such as this? For example, a user's blog might have 10 pages.

**ruby**

```
index = 1
downloads = []
page = open("http://#{user_name}.tumblr.com/page/#{index.to_s}") do |page|
  page.each_line do |line|
        downloads.push($&) if line =~ regex
    end
end
```

Comment: Does your ruby code actually open more than one page as it is?

Comment: ^^^ I'm such a goof. You're so right. Now I see how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after finishing up the bot I just wrote, I used a recursive solution. [Check out this post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902211/nodejs-making-the-while-loop-synchronous)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't appear that way.

where the first argument to `open` is validated in the open-uri source code [here](https://github.com/publicclass/open-uri/blob/master/lib/open-uri.js#L21), it validates the URI using [addressable](https://github.com/publicclass/addressable/blob/master/lib/addressable.js) whose `parse` method looks like it only finds one URI per string.

The conventional method would be to use a good old fashioned for loop.

Comment: The only problem is I wanted this to be dynamic. If I define a for loop, I would have to loop over a fixed length. Is this still possible maybe using async?