# How can I query AWS DynamoDB table synchronously from AWS Lambda using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, synchronous, aws-lambda

I have a use case where in I need to query a DynamoDB table and wait until I get the result or it has exceeded some predefined time before I get result. I understand making asynchronous requests from within a loop will not work but I need to achieve something like this:

```
while(true){
       data = queryDynamoDBSynchronously(params);
       if(data || count >5){
            (do something with data if not null);
             break;
        }else{
            count++;}
}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Look at the solutions to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902211/nodejs-making-the-while-loop-synchronous